# jQuery How do I put a limit to a decreasing value

Tags: jquery, input, limit

I hope someone can help me with the following 'problem'.

Starting with 700 credits, the client can buy items that appear in thumbnails(.box)
Adding thumbnails/items costs 25 credits, so when the client has less than 25 left, the add button should be disabled. (This works perfectly by the way)

However in the future I want more simple actions to decrease or increase the credits with diffrent amounts. I made a sample 'action' in my example, so when a client clicks the orange square it should decrease with 15. And that's what causing the trouble. Because I don't know how to put a limit to the diffrent decreasing values.

For example:  if there are 24 credits left, the client can't buy another box, but should be able to buy something for 15 credits.
(And never credits should never go below zero)

Can anyone help me accomplish this? Keep in mind I would also like to increase and decrease with more actions in the future. Thank you in advance.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9HbWh/)

**Code**
*JS*

```
var counter = 0;


$("#money").val(250);

$('#purchase').click(function() {
    var box = $('<div class="box"' + (counter) + '><div class="yellow"' + (counter) + '><div class="buy"' + (counter) + '></div></div></div>').appendTo('.container');
    $("#money").val(Number($("#money").val()) - 26);

    if ($("#money").val() < 25) {
        $('#purchase').prop("disabled", true);
    }

    $('.buy').click(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut();
     if ($("#money").val() < 25) {
        $('#purchase').prop("disabled", true);

        $("#money").val(Number($("#money").val()) - 15);
}
    });




});
```

*HTML*

```
<button id="purchase">Add a box </button>
<input id="money"></input>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Create a general function that runs after each addition/subtraction, which will disable or enable multiple DOM elements as appropriate depending on how much money is available.

Comment: Thank you for your response, that could be a possibility. Updatemoney() or something. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/RbnBs/1/

```
var counter = 0;


$("#money").val(250);

$('#purchase').click(function() {
    if($("#money").val() < 25)
        return; // or alert('not enough money');

    var box = $('<div class="box"' + (counter) + '><div class="yellow"' + (counter) + '><div class="buy"' + (counter) + '></div></div></div>').appendTo('.container');
    $("#money").val(Number($("#money").val()) - 25).triggerHandler('change');
});

$('#money').change(function(){
    $('#purchase').prop("disabled", $(this).val() < 25);
});

$('.container').on('click', '.buy', function() {
    if($("#money").val() < 15)
        return; // or alert('not enough money');
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $("#money").val(Number($("#money").val()) - 15).triggerHandler('change');;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll try to understand your changes and get back on it asap!

Comment: random beginner question; I notice now the if statement don't have to begin and end with curly brackets, is this a known fact for jquery?

Comment: You can have them if you like it, or not. I tend to omit them. And this is a Javascript question, not a jquery one.

Comment: Of course, only omit them when there is only ONE sentence in the if branch.